# checking if a file exists with a variable on python

Tags: python, windows, if-statement

i'm having a problem when i try to check if a file exists. The problem comes that the file name has to be defined by the user because its kind a "Autentication system", the problem is that no matter what password i put it always sende me back that it doesnt exists.

```
contador = 1 
def B():
    pregunta = int(input("Introduce la clave: "))
    if os.path.isfile(pregunta)== True:
       os.system("cls")
       print("Contraseña Correcta")
       seleccion()
    else:
        print("Contraseña Incorrecta")
        global contador
        contador +=1
        if contador <= 3:
           B()
        else:
             print("Se ha excedido el numero maximo de intentos")
             exit()
def C():
    pregunta2 = int(input("cambiar la clave o iniciar windows?"))
    if pregunta2 == ("cambiar la clave"):
       nuevaclave = int(input("Cual sera la nueva clave?"))
       archi=open("nuevaclave","w")
       archi.close()
       os.system("Attrib +H nuevaclave")
       os.remove(Pregunta)
       print("Se procedera al inicio del sistema")
       os.system("start explorer.exe")
       exit()
    elif pregunta2 == ("iniciar windows"):
         print("Se procedera al inicio del sistema")
         os.system("start explorer.exe")
         exit()
    else:
        print("No te entiendo")
        C()
print("Bienvenido al sistema de autenticacion")
import time
time.sleep(5)
import os
import os.path
os.chdir("D:\Marcos\Desktop")
if os.system("mkdir Clave") == 0:
   os.system("mkdir Clave")
   os.system("Attrib +H Clave")
   os.chdir("Clave")
   archi=open("12345","w")
   archi.close()
   os.system("cls")
   print("Se ha designado la clave predeterminada la cual es 12345")
 else:
     pass

time.sleep(5)
os.system("taskkill /f /im explorer.exe")
B()
```

I'm having trouble specifically with this part

```
def B():
       pregunta = int(input("Introduce la clave: "))
       if os.path.isfile(pregunta)== True:
          os.system("cls")
          print("Contraseña Correcta")
          seleccion()
       else:
           print("Contraseña Incorrecta")
           global contador
           contador +=1
           if contador <= 3:
              B()
           else:
               print("Se ha excedido el numero maximo de intentos")
               exit()
```

It's probably a newbie question but i have been started two days ago and i can't get through this problem.

Comment: Why are you converting the input to an int?

Comment: Just as a side note: You can use expressions that evaluate to boolean values directly as conditions for `if`, without comparing to `True`. So instead of `if os.path.isfile(pregunta)== True:` you can simply write `if os.path.isfile(pregunta):`.

Comment: Thanks @das-g but also with that it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `os.path.isfile(integer)` will always result in `False`. You're always converting input to an integer. You probably shouldn't. Try to do the same with `pregunta=raw_input(...)`

Comment: Nope, it doesnt work since i'm using python 3.4.3 and it doesnt recognize it.I'm sorry i'm too noob in this